# How to display uploaded PDF file in django adminsite

Tags: django, django-admin, embed

**I want to display uploaded(via FieldField) pdf file at Django adminsite. Without displaying pdf file, it's download automatically.**

Bellow, I share my code what I am trying:

**models.py file:**

```
from django.db import models
from common.models import SubCategory,QuestionHistory

# Create your models here.

class BigotoBochor(models.Model):
    question_history = models.ForeignKey(QuestionHistory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pdf_file = models.FileField(upload_to='bigotobochor')
```

**admin.py file:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import BigotoBochor
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

# Register your models here.

@admin.register(BigotoBochor)
class BigotoBochorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('question_history','subcategory','embed_pdf_file',)
    # list_editable = ('published',)
    list_filter = ('subcategory','question_history__board__name','question_history__year',)
    search_fields = ('question_history__year','question_history__board__name')
    list_per_page = 25


    # profile pic
    def embed_pdf_file(self,obj):
        if(obj.pdf_file != None and obj.pdf_file != "" ):
            return mark_safe('<embed src="{0}" type="application/pdf" width="50%" height="400px"/>'.format(obj.pdf_file.url,))
        
    embed_pdf_file.short_description = 'Question'
```

**How to display pdf file in adminsite?**

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display the pdf file on 'list_display', just

```
list_display = ('question_history','subcategory','pdf_file',)
```

will work.

Comment: It's just showing link. I used embed_pdf_file method for the purpose of displaying pdf file.

Comment: Click on the link and you will see the file, maybe..

Comment: It's download automatically. I want to display at admin site.

Answer (score 0):

In your model.py you have pdf_file but you are trying to display embed_pdf_file in the admin.py. see fix below

```
list_display = ('question_history','subcategory','pdf_file',)
```

Comment: It's just showing link. I used embed_pdf_file method for the purpose of displaying pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'embed_pdf')

    def embed_pdf(self, obj):
        # check for valid URL and return if no valid URL
        url = obj.pdf_file.url
        html = '<embed src="{url}" type="application/pdf">'
        formatted_html = format_html(html.format(url=obj.cover.url))
        return formatted_html
```

This will render pdf in a browser like this.

[image]

Ensure `X_FRAME_OPTIONS` is set properly in Django settings.

Comment: Please guide me how to set X_FRAME_OPTIONS properly. I am trying like X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM {SITE_DOMAIN}'. but same as before.

Comment: I have set `X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'`. Can you check if your options are being set correctly, open just the pdf URL in the browser, and check if it is loading correctly?

Comment: when I open url in the browser it's download directly.

Comment: Is `Content-Disposition` header being set anywhere in your server? This will affect if the file needs to be rendered or downloaded as an attachment. Can you try another browser also once?

Comment: I will inform you after trying.

Comment: All browsers do the same, download files automatically. I can not figure out how to check Content-Disposition set or not. Please help me.